# How can I preserve quotes in printing a Bash script's arguments?

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a Bash script that will print and pass complex arguments to another external program.

```
./script -m root@hostname,root@hostname -o -q -- 'uptime ; uname -a'
```

How do I print the raw arguments as such?

```
-m root@hostname,root@hostname -o -q -- 'uptime ; uname -a'
```

Using `$@` and `$*`, removes the single quotes around `uptime ; uname -a` which could cause undesired results. My script does not need to parse each argument. I just need to print / log the argument string and pass them to another program exactly how they are given.

I know I can escape the quotes with something like  `"'uptime ; uname -a'"`, but I cannot guarantee the user will do that.

Comment: Can't gurantee that the user will escape the quotes.

Comment: According to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472593/341661, although `echo $@` doesn't print out the quotes, $@ does "pass the quotes in background". I've tried this by writing 2 script: the 1st script passed "$@" to 2nd script, while the 2nd script prints "$1", and it worked

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion which asks more specifically about disabling `*` expansion (you can't do that either).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The quotes are removed before the arguments are passed to your script, so it's too late to preserve them. But you can preserve their effect when passing the arguments to the inner command, and reconstruct an equivalent quoted/escaped version of the arguments for printing.

For passing the arguments to the inner command `"$@"`—with the double quotes, $@ preserves the original word breaks, meaning that the inner command receives exactly the same argument list that your script did.

For printing, you can use the %q format in Bash's *printf* command to reconstruct the quoting.  Note that this won't always reconstruct the original quoting, but it will construct an *equivalent* quoted/escaped string.  For example, if you passed the argument `'uptime ; uname -a'` it might print `uptime\ \;\ uname\ -a` or `"uptime ; uname -a"` or any other equivalent (see [William Pursell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835933/how-can-i-preserve-quotes-in-printing-a-bash-scripts-arguments/10836089#10836089) for similar examples).

Here's an example of using these:

```
printf "Running command:"
printf " %q" innercmd "$@" # note the space before %q -- this inserts spaces between arguments
printf "\n"
innercmd "$@"
```

If you have Bash version 4.4 or later, you can use the `@Q` modifier on parameter expansions to add quoting. This tends to prefer using single quotes (as opposed to `printf %q`'s preference for escapes). You can combine this with `$*` to get a reasonable result:

```
echo "Running command: innercmd ${*@Q}"
innercmd "$@"
```

Note that `$*` mashes all arguments together into a single string with whitespace between them, which is normally not useful, but in this case each argument is individually quoted so the result is actually what you (probably) want. (Well, unless you changed [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_Field_Separators), in which case the "whitespace" between arguments will be the first character of `$IFS`, which may *not* be what you want.)

Answer (score 11):

Use ${@@Q} for a simple solution. To test it, put the lines below in a script, *bigQ*.

```
#!/bin/bash
line="${@@Q}"
echo $line
```

Run:

```
./bigQ 1 a "4 5" b="6 7 8"
'1' 'a' '4 5' 'b=6 7 8'
```

Comment: ```@Q``` is an expansion operation that stands for "The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input." https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: The `@Q` expansion operator is Bash 4+ only, and will not work e.g. on MacOS which is still stuck on Bash 3.

Comment: This is the only answer which actually preserves the quotes!
I'm working in a situation where literally only this solution works thanks!

Comment: Oddly, for me (`GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`), `${@@Q}` expands to the quoted string of the first list element. I had to use `${*@Q}` instead.

Answer (score 7):

If the user invokes your command as:

```
./script 'foo'
```

the first argument given to the script is the string `foo` without the quotes.  There is no way for your script to differentiate between that and any of the other methods by which it could get `foo` as an argument (eg `./script $(echo foo)` or `./script foo` or `./script "foo"` or `./script \f\o""''""o`).

Comment: Interesting. Guess I am out of luck for printing, but it seems that passing `"$@"` will still allow the external program to parse the args correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print the argument list as close as possible to what the user probably entered:

```
#!/bin/bash
chars='[ !"#$&()*,;<>?\^`{|}]'
for arg
do
    if [[ $arg == *"'"* ]]
    then
        arg=\""$arg"\"
    elif [[ $arg == *$chars* ]]
    then
        arg="'$arg'"
    fi
    allargs+=("$arg")    # ${allargs[@]} is to be used only for printing
done
printf '%s\n' "${allargs[*]}"
```

It's not perfect. An argument like `''\''"'` is more difficult to accommodate than is justified.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else already mentioned, when you access the arguments inside of your script, it's too late to know which arguments were quote when it was called. However, you can requote the arguments that contain spaces or other special characters that would need to be quoted to be passed as parameters.

Here is a Bash implementation based on [Python's `shlex.quote(s)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/shlex.py#L321) that does just that:

```
function quote() {
  declare -a params
  for param; do
    if [[ -z "${param}" || "${param}" =~ [^A-Za-z0-9_@%+=:,./-] ]]; then
      params+=("'${param//\'/\'\"\'\"\'}'")
    else
      params+=("${param}")
    fi
  done
  echo "${params[*]}"
}
```

Your example slightly changed to show empty arguments:

```
quote -m root@hostname,root@hostname -o -q -- 'uptime ; uname -a' ''
```

Output:

```
-m root@hostname,root@hostname -o -q -- 'uptime ; uname -a' ''
```

Comment: this does work in some cases, but fails in others.  Almost, but not quite for my use case.

Comment: BTW, `function funcname() {` merges the POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` and the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with *both* POSIX sh and legacy ksh, and for no benefit whatsoever. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have tried to call Bash like `script --argument="--arg-inner=1 --arg-inner2"`.

Unfortunately, the previous solutions don't help in my case.

The definitive solution was:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Fix given array argument quotation
function quote() {
    local QUOTED_ARRAY=()
    for ARGUMENT; do
        case ${ARGUMENT} in
            --*=*)
                QUOTED_ARRAY+=( "${ARGUMENT%%=*}=$(printf "%q" "${ARGUMENT#*=}")" )
                shift
            ;;
            *)
                QUOTED_ARRAY+=( "$(printf " %q" "${ARGUMENT}")" )
            ;;
        esac
    done
    echo ${QUOTED_ARRAY[@]}
}

ARGUMENTS="$(quote "${@}")"

echo "${ARGUMENTS}"
```

The result in the case of [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) is `--argument=--arg-inner=1\ --arg-inner2` which is logically the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution, and it also works in the `sh` shell:

#### File *script1.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

concatenated_string=""

for ARG in "$@"; do
    concatenated_string="${concatenated_string}'${ARG}' "
done

echo "${concatenated_string}"
eval "${concatenated_string}"
```

When I invoke `script1.sh` with:
`./script1.sh sh -c "serve -l 9527 -s dist"`

The output will be:

```
'sh' '-c' 'serve -l 9527 -s dist'

   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                   │
   │   Serving!                                        │
   │                                                   │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:9527       │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://192.168.2.102:9527   │
   │                                                   │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As you can see, the first line echo the string which preserved quotes; the second line direct execute `sh -c "serve -l 9527 -s dist"` by using `eval`. Note that, you can pass any command you want to eval as `script1.sh`'s arguments.

Comment: But ['eval' is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)(?).

Answer (score -2):

Just separate each argument using **quotes**, and the **nul character**:

```
#! /bin/bash


sender () {
    printf '"%s"\0' "$@"
}


receiver () {
    readarray -d '' args < <(function "$@")
}


receiver "$@"
```

As commented by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).

Comment: Note: The `-d` option of `readarray` is only available in 5.0 or newer versions of Bash.