# Preserving escapes in bash arguments $@

Tags: bash, escaping

related to this: [Preserve Quotes in bash arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835933/preserve-quotes-in-bash-arguments)

A simple example, where I simply run a command with `nohup`...

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup "$@"

...

./myscript gedit some\ file\ with\ spaces.txt
```

This works fine. However, I have no idea how to keep the correct bits of the arguments escaped when using an intermediate variable...

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="$@"
printf "%q\n" "$CMD" #for debugging
nohup $CMD
```

I've tried a few permutations and nothing works in all cases. What am I missing? Ideally I would like to be able to modify `$CMD` before `nohup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an array.

```
cmd=( "$@" )
printf '%q\n' "${cmd[@]}"
nohup "${cmd[@]}"
```

Scalar variables (strings) are NUL-delimited, so they can't contain an argument list (which is, by its nature, NUL-separated).

See also [the BashSheet entry on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays), [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) (explaining how to use arrays), and [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (explaining the pitfalls caused by *not* doing it this way).

Comment: Thumbs up for references to the BashFAQ

Comment: Thumbs up for stopping me from pulling my hair out with a similar problem.