# How to preserve doubles quoted arguments passed to a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to run a .sh file by passing few arguments. The file contains the following.

```
# escape special characters
ESCAPED_REPLACE=$(printf '%s ' "$@" | sed -e 's/[$()"]/\\&/g')

echo "After replace"
echo $ESCAPED_REPLACE

npx codeceptjs "$ESCAPED_REPLACE" --plugins allure
```

Following is a sample list of arguments. As it shows the last argument contains double quotes. Which I need to preserve here

```
./test.sh run --steps --grep "Verifying login"
```

The issue is once I print the ESCAPED_REPLACE the quotes are lost. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Just use it as `npx codeceptjs "$@" --plugins allure`

Comment: Note: `$ESCAPSED_REPLACE` contains a typo

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I want to escape the $ and the brackets passing directly won't work if the argument inside the quotes contains any special character

Comment: I need to escape special characters in the argument list before passing it to the npx command. Is there a way I can preserve the quotes

Comment: Does it work when you do `./test.sh run --steps --grep '"Verifying login"'`?

Comment: `print the ESCAPED_REPLACE the quotes are lost` They are not there in the first place. You have to add the quotes if you want them, like `--grep "\"Verifying login\""` for example, or like above. But adding quotes does _not_ mean it's going to be one word, it's going to be two separate words after word splitting. Anyway, re-read an introduction to shell, research quoting, bash arrays and word splitting expansion in shell.

Comment: Does my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835933/preserve-quotes-in-bash-arguments/10836225#10836225) help clarify what's going on?

Comment: @Kavin404, if your question is about the proper variable escaping then maybe you should use `printf '%q ' "$@"` instead of your `sed` trick.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes that are passed to your script are printed correctly. However, in your example `./test.sh run --steps --grep "Verifying login"` you don't pass any quotes to the script, since bash interprets them before `test.sh` even runs.

To pass quotes to your script, you have to escape them:

```
./test.sh run --steps --grep "\"Verifying login\""
```

Anyways, I'm not sure you really need `sed -e 's/[$()"]/\\&/g'`. To me this seems like a misunderstanding of how bash interprets special symbols.  When you write `"$variable"` the special symbols inside `variable` are not interpreted. Therefore, you normally don't have to quote the content of `variable`. I'd assume the following to work:

**Content of `test.sh`**

```
#! /bin/sh
npx codeceptjs "$@" --plugins allure
```

**Execution**

```
./test.sh run --steps --grep "Verifying login"
```

Comment: or use a simple quote around the double-quoted string, like this: `'"Verifying login"'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file name: test

echo "K: ${@@K}"

echo "find ${@@K}"
eval "find ${@@K}"
```

This *should* pass everything to `find` just as if you typed it directly

```
$ ./test ../Downloads -name "This is a test.pdf"
K: '../Downloads' '-name' 'This is a test.pdf'
find '../Downloads' '-name' 'This is a test.pdf'
../Downloads/This is a test.pdf
```

If I am reading your question right, that is what you are trying to do. Special characters will be interpreted in the shell before passing them to your script unless you escape them first:

`$ ./test \$var1 "\$var2 \$var3" '$var4 single quotes work too'`