# bash: quote var with quotes

Tags: bash, quotes, double-quotes

I try to make a dummy script for debugging. The script should pass the command and all params to syslog. But when I get a param which has quotes I only get a failure.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
param="$*"

logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "$*"
#logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "$param"
#logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "$(echo "$param")"
#logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "${param//\"/}"
#logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "${param[@]}"
```

I tryd some variants I found, but nothing works.

```
# d-iptables -L dkdsdds "ddd"
+ param='-L dkdsdds ddd'
++ echo '-L dkdsdds ddd'
+ logger -t /usr/sbin/d-iptables -p local3.debug '-L dkdsdds ddd'
logger: invalid option -- L

Usage:
 logger [options] [message]

Options:
 -d, --udp             use UDP (TCP is default)
 -i, --id              log the process ID too
 -f, --file <file>     log the contents of this file
 -h, --help            display this help text and exit
 -n, --server <name>   write to this remote syslog server
 -P, --port <number>   use this UDP port
 -p, --priority <prio> mark given message with this priority
 -s, --stderr          output message to standard error as well
 -t, --tag <tag>       mark every line with this tag
 -u, --socket <socket> write to this Unix socket
 -V, --version         output version information and exit
```

Comment: Sounds like [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Your immediate problem is that you want `"$@"` but I'm guessing it won't take you all the way where you think you want to be going. But just don't want to go there.

Comment: I only want to esape the quotes inside the var, that I can pass them as message to logger

Comment: If you are trying to forward arguments to some other command verbatim then just use `"$@"` when calling the other command as tripleee indicated. If that *doesn't* work for what you are trying to do (and I'm certain it will) then edit your question to indicate *why* you think it doesn't.

Comment: If you're going to post your own answer, post it as a new answer; don't edit it into the question -- that way that answer can be upvoted/downvoted/commented on/etc. separate from the question.

Comment: sorry, I dont wanted to whip the good hints, which helped me to find my way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you change your script to `#!/bin/bash` and use

```
logger -t $0 -p local3.debug -- "$(printf "%q " "$@")"
```

You need the `--` so logger doesn't think the `-L` is one of its options.

Comment: its not bad, but in syslog I dont get the quotes -> /usr/sbin/d-iptables: -L dkdsdds ddd :(

Comment: You cannot: your shell removes them before your script even starts

Comment: really sure the is no way?! IFS, for loop, or something else?

Comment: Yes, really sure. Assuming your shell is bash, there is a defined list of expansions that occurs before commands are launched. Quote removal is one of those expansions. Your script will never know how the user quoted the arguments.

Comment: Check my answer.  To preserve them?  No way.  To add them after they are removed (or missing)... yes.

Comment: found a way for reqoute: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24179878/1426827 -- this is better than nothing :)

Comment: @Thomas, that `requote` function given there has some serious (ie. security-impacting, if anything evaluates the output) bugs. You're much better off relying on `printf %q` instead, as given in this answer -- perhaps the ksh93 implementation if you have that shell available, as its output is somewhat easier-to-read than the bash one.

Comment: I have seen you have added some comments to Chen Levy answer. It means, with your corrections, the function is more safe? Have you a complete snippet?

Comment: No, the corrections I've offered thus far don't make Chen's answer more safe, only higher-performance.

Comment: was the function or better "usage" in my question edit more safe?

Comment: The usage in your edit was `eval`-safe, inasmuch as the output from `requote` always went through `printf %q`, but it compromised on correctness to get there (double-escaping contents).

Comment: Probably, building a good equivalent to ksh's `printf %q` for bash needs to be its own question. (The ksh one does everything Chen's answer provided out-of-the-box while also being correct and safe in the corner cases, whereas while the bash `printf %q`'s output is syntactically correct for the parser, it's not very easy for humans to read in the simple cases, which is presumably why you were adding `requote` to it in addition).

Comment: @Thomas, ...to be clear, the output of glenn's answer should give you everything you need to distinguish between `d-iptables -L foo bar` and `d-iptables -L "foo bar"`, without needing `requote`; for the first case, it would run logger with `foo bar`, for the second, `foo\ bar` -- which is quite correct, as `d-iptables -L "foo bar"` and `d-iptables -L foo\ bar` are indistinguishable to the shell. It's just not as human-readable as some other formulations would be.

Comment: okay, now I can see that the answer also works without the requote. I have not checked with the same param input - I testet before with the requote function. Thanks to make it clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

First you have tagged this as bash, but you are using /bin/sh (which is either bourne or dash).  Next your logger is reading the - as an argument.  Just quote it better.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
param="\"$@\""     # quotes removed by the shell

logger -t $0 -p local3.debug "'$param'"  # expand, then strong quote
```

Comment: Why in the world would you want to assign an array to a scalar variable?

Comment: Holy Perl lingo, Batman!  B/c in this case, the array is a string.  It is in fact how the OP was treating it, and I see no reason to make it an array.  Why would you want to assign a string to an array?  No need.

Comment: The OP *wants* to make a string from their array, yes, but `param="\"$@\""` isn't actually doing that in a useful way. I mean, if you had `set -- "first item" "second item"`, the desired output is presumably a single string that shows those quoted together, right? Something like `param="'first item' 'second item'"`? Your code doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: ...by contrast, `printf -v param '%q ' "$@"` would (in bash) assign something like `param='first\ item second\ item'`, making it clear which whitespace is syntactical and which whitespace is literal. (In ksh, it would do even better, following the `'first item' 'second item'` model).

Comment: ksh is not germane.  And it doesn't matter if printf shows the literal/syntactical, b/c logger will eat them and it will be obscured in the final product.  In addition, logger takes ONE argument-- a string as the message.  So, you are coding on an assumption that there is more than one argument, when there can't be.  ? `logger "this is" "messed up"` is not a valid behavior.

Comment: Sure, but `logger '"this is" "messed up"'` is both valid **and desirable**, inasmuch as the OP's question is about passing "all params" (which specifies **multiple** parameters) through in a way that honors "quotes" (plural, from the OP's question).

Comment: So yes, we're combining multiple arguments into one argument, but doing that in a way that disregards the original argument boundaries is throwing away information.

Comment: See also the OP's use of the `requote` function in the answer they (previously) edited into the question (check history); `requote` has no purpose if one **doesn't** intend to represent the distinction between literal and syntactic whitespace in multiple arguments.